# css animation for line to disappear

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to do an animation for a logo where it appears to be pulled up by a rope(which will be a vertical black line) from the bottom of the page to the top.

I would like it if the rope disappeared behind the logo as it goes up but I'm unsure how to do it.

I know how to do CSS translations so moving the logo is fine, it is just the disappearing rope part I am unsure of.

I would prefer css but javascript is no problem.

Thanks

EDIT: Adding some of the CSS and HTML so far:

```
body {
background-color: White;"
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
display: inline-block;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: blue;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
p.one {
color: black; 
font-family: arial;
padding-top: 50px;
align="center";
}

</style>

</head>

<body> 

<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#Products">Our Products</a></li>  
<li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
<h1>Home</h1>

<p class="one", align="center">Text</p>
```

Comment: Would you be able to post some code you already have, if that would be ok? Then indicate where you would be looking to place the rope code? ^-__-^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This appears to be a request and not a question at all. Please read [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before posting.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Hi, only started this page about an hour ago so it's REALLY scant :) I'd like it to be in the center and end up in the center between h1 and the nav bar, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding some code! :). Welcome to the site also!

Answer (score 1):

- You could animate the rope (also with css translate) at the same time you animate the logo. Use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element.
- You could draw the rope with HTML canvas `rect();` and animate its height.